# ant exec task error with code=3

Tags: java, bash, ant

Im trying to invoke a bash scrip from an ant target. This is my target :

```
<target name="report" depends="test">
    <!-- Step 3: Create coverage report -->
    <exec executable="./checkStyle.sh"
            failonerror="true"
            osfamily="unix"/>
    <jacoco:report>

        <!-- This task needs the collected execution data and ... -->
        <executiondata>
            <file file="${result.exec.file}" />
        </executiondata>

        <!-- the class files and optional source files ... -->
        <structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${result.classes.dir}" />
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${src.dir}" />
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>

        <!-- to produce reports in different formats. -->
        <html destdir="${result.report.dir}" />
        <csv destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.csv" />
        <xml destfile="${result.report.dir}/report.xml" />
    </jacoco:report>
</target>
```

And my bash script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
DEST_FOLDER='./target/checkstyle'
CLASSES_FILE='classes.txt'
REPORT_FILE='report.xml'
mkdir -p "$DEST_FOLDER"

rm -f "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_FILE"
rm -f "$DEST_FOLDER/$REPORT_FILE"

find ./project -name "*.java" >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_FILE"
while read p; do 
    java -jar ./utilJars/checkstyle-6.5-all.jar -c ./sun_checks.xml -f xml $p >> "$DEST_FOLDER/$REPORT_FILE"
done < $DEST_FOLDER/$CLASSES_FILE
```

When typing ./checkStyle everything works fine, but when I try "ant report" the following error is raised:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/luci/workspace/operations/build.xml:60: exec returned: 3

Total time: 4 seconds
```

I`ve searched on google and that code seems to be "permision denied", but i dont know how i could solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of ./, did you try giving the entire path to the script?

Comment: why not use ant task for checkstyle: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html  ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally with Ant (and Java), you cannot directly execute shell scripts. You need to execute the interpreter/shell and give the script as an argument.

For example:

```
    <exec executable="/bin/bash" failonerror="true" osfamily="unix">
        <arg value="-c"/>
        <arg value="./checkStyle.sh"/>
    </exec>
```