# What does code number 3 returned by exec Ant mean?

Tags: ant

all I execute an Ant file, it fails and am receiving `"exec returned code 3"`, without any other explanations! I just would like to know what is the meaning of the code number 3 in Ant? Thanks

Comment: You should look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647280/ant-exec-task-error-with-code-3

Comment: Also please share your code. You should edit your question.

Comment: Hey limonik thank you for your answer, i didn't share the code because all i wanted is to understand the meaning of the exec code 3 in general way, i looked for it on the net and found nothing, your answer was helpful, thank you.